# Formcontrol disable input value preview

Tags: angular, angular-material, dropdown, angular-forms, angular11

I made a stepper, and I want to input a default value into a select. To do so I use the two way binding `[(value)]` property. And it worked.

But as soon as I add a `[formControl]` property, the input value disappear. It's still there programattically but do not appear anymore in the dropdown.

Here is an example of step :

```
  <mat-step state="class" [stepControl]="firstFormControl">
    <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Foo Label</ng-template>
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Foo Label</mat-label>
        <mat-select [(value)]="myVar" [formControl]="firstFormControl" required>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let i of customCollection" [value]="i">
            {{i.name}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
      <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </mat-step>
```

Here is the form definition :

```
public firstFormGroup: FormGroup;
public firstFormControl: FormControl;
```

```
this.firstFormControl = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
   firstCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

the `myVar` value used in the `[(value)]` property is completely external to the form and just refers to one of the `customCollection` elements.

Any idea on how i could fix this ? Many thanks ! Kev'

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use both template driven form and reactive form on a single control.

You can opt out for a reactive form control so you can access it inside the component code.
So remove that part as following

`<mat-select [formControl]="firstFormControl">`

inside your component you can set this control as required

```
get myVar(): any {
   return this.form.get('firstFormControl').value;
}
```

where `firstFormControl` is defined as inside a FormGroup object. For example, inside ngInit method

```
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({'firstFormControl', ['', [Validators.required]]});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, proceeding so, how can I input a default value displayed in the dropdown ? Does inputing it in the firstFormControl would make the job ?

Comment: If i am to understand right, we should use the "setValue()" method on the form ? I am quite confuse because my object here is composed of an Id and a name. So I struggle to input this correctly to have the id used programmatically and the name displayed to the user.

Answer (score 0):

For those who get there.

I was missusing the formcontrol and formGroup.

I've deleted `firstFormControl` and instead use the property `formControlName="firstCtrl"` into the mat-select line.

I've deleted `[(value)]=myVar` property to be in a full reactive form and stop using the template driven form.

The from the typescript you can input a default value with the line

```
this.firstFormGroup.get('firstCtrl').setValue( this.customCollection[2].id );
```

See ya !